# Call method on Existing Activity from another Activity's fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment `HostEditFragment` which is loaded up by activity `HostEditActivity`. When I finish editing in the fragment I'd like to call a method on `MainActivity`. I'm trying to do it with an `Interface` and `intent` at the moment but it starts a new `MainActivity` and doesn't seem to work.

Just wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

I think it's creating a new `MainActivity` rather than using the existing one as `SfnViewerFragment` is coming back as null. I need it to be the existing `MainActivity` and `SfnViewerFragment`.

Here's some skeletal code so you can see what I've tried.

HostEditFragment:

```
public class HostEditFragment extends Fragment {
    OnViewerEditedListener callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            callback = (OnViewerEditedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnViewerEditedListener");
        }
    }

    public void saveHost() {
    //...
        callback.onViewerEdited(id);

    }

    public interface OnViewerEditedListener {
        public void onViewerEdited(Long id);
    }
}
```

HostEditActivity:

```
public class HostEditActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements HostEditFragment.OnViewerEditedListener {
    public void onViewerEdited(Long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        Uri viewerUri;
        if (data != null) {
            //....
        } else {
            Long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", -1);
            if (id != -1) {
                onViewerEdited(id);
            }
        }

    public void onViewerEdited(Long id) {
        SfnViewerFragment sfnViewerFragment = (SfnViewerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0");
        sfnViewerFragment.recreateWebView(id);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need start HostEditActivity with startActivityForResult method from MainActivity firstly, and when you finished editing need setResult about editing (to data intent) and back to MainActivity then check have a change or no. Here you can read how to use : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html   and here extra example: http://startandroid.ru/en/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult

Comment: Have you thought about setting flags on your intent, to signal to Android that you want to reuse your activity instead of recreating it?

Comment: @Aster How do I go about that? I'm primarily an iOS dev and a bit lost here! haha

Comment: See documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. It tells you a lot about the activity stack of Android. And also about the flags "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK", "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" and "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" that you can set on your intent.